# Java - Read text from PDF on specific points

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have made a program using Java to read PDF files that always have the same format. The PDFs have information i need to upload to a database.

So far i have managed to read the entire PDF and get all the text included without problem.

My problem is that sometimes the info on the PDF is not complete, and the parts where no info is given is blank, so my extracted text is different from the ones that have all the info.

How can i read the PDF on specific points, to see if there is info, or not, so i can know if a specific point is blank, then i assign empty.

I need to know if the pdf have some spots blank.

In the attached picture is the pdf format.

[image]

Comment: which pdf library are you using?

Comment: Hi, i am using pdf-box.2.0.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101748/extracting-text-from-an-area-with-pdfbox